# How to set value to textbox in c# from jagged array?

Tags: c#, winforms

In the picture I want the save button to save the entries of customers to a jagged array and then when I press the show button the saved names should show into the text box below.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace week5hw
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string[][] str = new string[3][];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String names = textBox1.Text;
            str[0] = new string[5];
            str[0][0] = names;
       }

        private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 

        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why do you use a jagged array since user can only enter one value ?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It seems this a homework. Even your namespace says namespace week5hw(Week 5 home work). Can you please try it first?

Comment: Dear Damith, I tried but the problem is here I do not know to set the array values into text box.

Comment: and also each time it overwrite the value by clicking

Comment: Again, why the Jagged Array.  Is this a requirement of the assignment?  As written, it makes no sense for the problem.  Give more details.

Comment: textbox1.Text += sometext + "\r\n";

Comment: the teacher asked students to do it with jagged I do not know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't see how a jagged array applies here.  You need to give more details about how the program is supposed to work.

At any rate, you need to declare an `int` variable to track how many of those spots have been used.  That variable can also be used to determine which "row" in your jagged array to store the entered name in.

Might look something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    int count=0;
    string[][] str = new string[3][];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "The number of free space in room is: " + str.Length;
        textBox2.Multiline = true;   
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            if (count < str.Length)
            {
                str[count] = new string[] { textBox1.Text };
                count++;
                label1.Text = "The number of free space in room is: " + (str.Length - count);
                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox1.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No space left!");
            }
        }                
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Clear();
        for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
        {               
            textBox2.AppendText(str[i][0] + "\r\n");
        }
    }

}
```